# CPLEX ERROR 1803 "Failure on temporary file write"

Tags: parameters, websphere, cplex

I have to solve a Model with a big Data Base. After a running time of about 12 or 18hours I got the Error 1803 "Failure on temporary file write". I already tried to fix the problem by adjusting the following Parameters: CPX_PARAM_TILIM, CPX_PARAM_MEMORYEMPHASIS, CPX_PARAM_EPAGAP, CPX_PARAM_RELOBJDIF

For the next run I will try to adjust the Parameters CPX_PARAM_TRELIM and CPX_PARAM_WORKMEM.

Does anybody have another idea to fix the error?

Additional information:

I am using the direct API of IBM ILOG Cplex 12.10. at my Lenovo ThinkPadE595.
Information about the laptop:
System: Windows 10 pro
Processor: AMD Ryzen 7, 3700U
Graficship: Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx 2.30 GHz
Memory: 16GB, 2600MHz
Harddisk: 237GB

The Model has about 6570 input Data within Excel, 160 constraints, 150 variable Parameters and 43 decision Variables

Comment: How big is your problem (variables, constraints etc)? What language and API are you using? What kind of system are you using (Windows? Linux? Mac?) How much memory? How big is your temporary filesystem? Is there any CPLEX log file output or stuff on the console?

Comment: I don't have any log file outputs when I got the error message. I am not sure where I can find the size of the temporary filesystem. I hope I could answer your question

Comment: OK, look at enabling the logging from inside CPLEX. See here for the IBM documentation: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=s-cpxxsetlogfilename-cpxsetlogfilename

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess without logs, and I suggest you follow Tim's advice to enable logs.  But my first hypothesis would be that CPLEX ran out of disk space while writing to the files. Another would be that it's only after these 12 or 18 hours that CPLEX tried to write to the disk, and it failed for any reason.

The two important parameters with respect to this topic are [`workmem`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=parameters-memory-available-working-storage) and [`mip.strategy.file`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=parameters-node-storage-file-switch).  To avoid any issue with files, you could try to set the workmem to something closer to the amount of memory on your machine than the default 2 GB, and disable using files.

In the Interactive, this would be `set workmem 12288` to set workmem to 12 GB, and `set mip.strategy.file 0` to disable node files.

You will find more examples of using these flags in [this post](https://xavier-nodet.medium.com/cplex-memory-usage-for-mips-4eb737f89e7a).